# Accepting only UTF8 letters with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to allow Chinese, Japanese (Hiragana,Katakana, Kanji), Korean, and basically any unicode letter.  I would just like the first character to be a letter

```
$pattern = '/\p{L}[\p{L}\p{N} _.-]+/u';
if(!preg_match($pattern, $subuser)){
    //Error
}
```

However my pattern seems to accept strings with numbers at the front.  When I added:

```
'/^\p{L}[\p{L}\p{N} _.-]+$/u'
```

No strings were accepted.  I have tried using \p{Hiragana} etc but with no real luck.  Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do your test strings contain anything besides letters, digits, ASCII space, ASCII underscore, ASCII period and ASCII dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php

$lines = array('12345', 'w123', 'hello');

$valid = array_filter($lines, function($line){
  return preg_match('/^\p{L}{1,}/iu', $line);
});

var_dump($valid);
```

Comment: This only checks if the first character is a letter, nothing more. (And the `{1,}` is a) inelegant - that's what the `+` quantifier is for and b) useless since it doesn't matter how many letters match at the start as long as it's at least one. So you can drop it altogether)

Comment: @TimPietzcker agreed; though I did show the + quantifier as the first comment :) --> but you are correct, it isn't _really_ necessary, but it _does_ depict a more explicit story. Removing the quantifier would be at best a micro-optimization and at worst, an unnecessary obfuscation for someone that is struggling with the syntax already. I'd go with readability in this case :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Just another standalone note. As he learns more about regex (which we are all continually doing), he will no doubt realize that {1,} is not necessary, but he will be glad he knows that it exists and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

The holy grail when it comes to sanitation: http://htmlpurifier.org/
It cleanses all data and will only allow utf-8 characters to pass. 
Some recommended reading on characters: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html